# how to use REST.Post with --form data in the robot framework

Tags: rest, python-requests, robotframework

I'm getting "curl" in the postman like this.

```
# curl
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:8080/RegisterService.aspx' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--form 'service="getkey"'

#response
1gydaDSDldhq2e21d7wqlKLDS
```

However, when I create this API in the robot framework with RESTInstance. This is the outcome

```
'body': 'CEcxd4bMRFGWrQQmWbn+msMNrsjGKiUJQGKMmSmT0drjBGhyg/d3LXs8PeGreGRUubYJe1E8oqKy7zHUrWEM45Tjd+H9u158...'
```

My code

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ${CURDIR}/imports/api_imports.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Check Encrypt
    ${headers}    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=multipart/form-data
    ${data}=    Create Dictionary    service=getkey
    ${response}    REST.Post    https://localhost:8080/RegisterService.aspx    body=${data}    headers=${headers}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario one usually uses the `files` parameter.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Check Encrypt
    ${data}=    Evaluate    {'service': (None, 'getkey')}
    ${response}=    POST On Session    https://localhost:8080/RegisterService.aspx    files=${data}
```

Using the files parameter in the `POST On Session` Request keyword the payload will be passed to the requests post method as is. There is no need to set the headers `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` explicitly and the library will add for us.